# Hive window lookback by date

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hive

I've the following table

| Date | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 2024-02-01 | Luke |
| 2024-02-01 | Alice |
| 2024-02-01 | John |
| 2024-02-01 | John |
| 2024-02-02 | Mark |
| 2024-02-02 | Alice |
| 2024-02-02 | Mark |
| 2024-02-03 | John |
| 2024-02-03 | John |
| 2024-02-03 | Alice |
| 2024-02-04 | John |
| 2024-02-04 | Alice |
| 2024-02-04 | James |
| 2024-02-05 | James |
| 2024-02-05 | Alice |
| 2024-02-05 | John |
| 2024-02-06 | Mark |
| 2024-02-06 | Alice |
| 2024-02-06 | Mark |
| 2024-02-06 | Alice |
| 2024-02-07 | John |
| 2024-02-07 | Alice |

I need to count the amount of distinct names for each date, with a lookback window of 3 days. This is what I came up with:

```sql
select distinct(
         date_key, 
         count(*) over (
           partition by date_key 
           order by unix_timestamp(date_key, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
           range between 259200 preceding and current row   -- 259200 is 3 days in seconds
       )
from my_schema.names_table
```

However, this is the result I'm getting

```
{"col1":"2024-02-01","col2":4}
{"col1":"2024-02-02","col2":3}
{"col1":"2024-02-06","col2":4}
{"col1":"2024-02-07","col2":2}
{"col1":"2024-02-03","col2":3}
{"col1":"2024-02-04","col2":3}
{"col1":"2024-02-05","col2":3}
```

Not only have I been unable to get it into their own columns but the numbers are wrong, because the result should be like

| Date | Unique names |
| --- | --- |
| 1/2/24 | 3 |
| 2/2/24 | 4 |
| 3/2/24 | 4 |
| 4/2/24 | 4 |
| 5/2/24 | 3 |
| 6/2/24 | 4 |
| 7/2/24 | 4 |

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure it out after a long while, the problem was on the `partition by`, it was not needed since I needed to look at all the data in this case. Here's the version that works

```sql
select distinct date_key, 
                count(distinct name) over (
                  order by unix_timestamp(date_key, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
                  range between 259200 preceding and current row)
from my_schema.names_table
```

This will return the follwing
| date_key      | unique_names |
|------------|-------|
| 2024-02-01 | 3     |
| 2024-02-02 | 4     |
| 2024-02-03 | 4     |
| 2024-02-04 | 5     |
| 2024-02-07 | 4     |
| 2024-02-05 | 4     |
| 2024-02-06 | 4     |

For any spark-sql users who come across this, the `count(distinct(name))` will not work on a window function, you'll have to use `approx_count_distinct(name)`

Answer (score 0):

Create a sub-query that returns a row for each name/date combination that should be counted in the final result (called `relevant_dates` in the code below).

Then group this intermediate result by date and count the distinct names in in each group:

```sql
WITH relevant_dates AS 
  (SELECT Name, explode(sequence(Date, date_add(Date, 2))) AS Date 
    FROM names_table)
SELECT 
  Date, 
  collect_set(Name) AS names, 
  size(collect_set(Name)) AS unique_names 
FROM 
  relevant_dates 
GROUP BY Date 
ORDER BY Date
```

Output:

```
+----------+--------------------------+------------+
|Date      |names                     |unique_names|
+----------+--------------------------+------------+
|2024-02-01|[Alice, Luke, John]       |3           |
|2024-02-02|[Mark, Alice, Luke, John] |4           |
|2024-02-03|[Mark, Alice, Luke, John] |4           |
|2024-02-04|[Mark, Alice, James, John]|4           |
|2024-02-05|[Alice, James, John]      |3           |
|2024-02-06|[Mark, Alice, James, John]|4           |
|2024-02-07|[Mark, Alice, James, John]|4           |
|2024-02-08|[Mark, Alice, John]       |3           |
|2024-02-09|[Alice, John]             |2           |
+----------+--------------------------+------------+
```